# How can I access the last attribute of an XML element using SimpleXML?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, cxml

I am using SimpleXML to parse through a cXML document. I can't figure out how to access an attribute from the deepest element in the document. When I parse for the attribute "currency" in the xml snippet below it doesn't exist. I figured out that this only occurs on the deepest elements. Is there a way that I can parse this document using SimpleXML?

Example portion of an XML document I am attempting to parse.

```
<ItemOut name="ItemOut">
<ItemDetail name="ItemDetail">
    <UnitPrice name="UnitPrice">
        <Money currency="USD">12.99</Money>
    </UnitPrice>
</ItemDetail>
```

I have tried using the json encode/decode way...

```
$simpleXml=simplexml_load_string($xml);
$json = json_encode($simpleXml);
$xmlArray = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

and using SimpleXML object... 
 
`$xmlObject = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);`
Here is a picture of the
[array structure of the parsed document.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcDrN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to run

```
<?php
$xmlObject = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$currency = $xmlObject-> ItemDetail -> UnitPrice -> Money -> attributes() -> currency;
?>
```

That will read your currency attribute and return `EUR` in your case

Comment: Thanks you very much!